# How can I edit the identical part of multiple files at once?

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I have multiple HTML files that form a small website. Several lines of code are duplicated at the top of the files (although the `<title>` differs), and a few lines are duplicated at the bottom.

I could use a pre-compiler like Jekyll, and use layouts so I only have to change the code once, but I feel this adds unnecessary complexity to the project. I could use regexes (which is what I'm currently doing, using [DirDo.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/DirDo.vim)), but this is a bit of a hassle.

So, is there any plugin that detects the identical parts of a set of files, and allows you to edit all of them at once? Or are there any other ways of doing this that I might not have thought of?

Comment: I would take the time to invest into using a precompiler like Jekyll, I think you'll be happier in the long run.  It makes making even minor changes to your common pieces of the website very simple, and it is a pretty simple framework to use.

Comment: One option is to use `sed` the stream editor. Sed is a non interactive editor, for batch editing multiple files. Also it is part of the same family as `vi`. Having said that I could use a pre-processor, there is a good rule in software “say it only once”, if you find your self saying/writing it more than once, then you need to modularise (function calls, includes, …).

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, this problem can be broken down into two parts:

1. Applying an edit to multiple files
2. Repeating the same edit

For 1., you're using the *DirDo* plugin; alternatives would be the built-in `:argdo`, `:bufdo`, etc.

For 2., you can use any (combination of) Vim commands. The most powerful one is `:substitute`, using a `:[range]` to select the lines, and regular expression to (find the point to) modify the text in those line(s).

You could also record a macro, and re-apply that via `:normal! @a`. Of, if this is a single edit at the start of a single line, a repeat via `:[address]normal! .` would suffice (but is limited to a single edit operation and the fact that `:normal` positions the cursor at the beginning of the line).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CtrlSF.vim](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim/) to search for a given pattern in all the files, and then simultaneously edit the part around the search results using [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors). There are some limitations though, e.g. you cannot add or delete lines, (see `README.md`).